# NWjs - Building Angular 2 Desktop Apps

Tags: javascript, angular, nwjs

I am trying to build an Angular 2 Desktop App with NWjs. What is the entry point?

Any examples of Building Angular 2 Desktop Apps with NW.js

Answer (score 1):

### *A proper setup for those who want to develop Desktop Apps using Angular2 & NW.js*

NW.js allows the developer to specify either a template (e.g. index.html) or an entry script like you mentioned.

I advise you to go check the awesome NW.js Community Projects on https://nwutils.io

There is on there an example NW.js Angular2 Boilerplate App you should refer to: https://github.com/nwutils/nw-angular-cli-example

A typical way to follow when developing NW.js Apps using Angular2 is to set an entry script `entry.js`. During development, serve your Angular App like you would in a normal Angular setup (i.e. `ng serve`), and run your NW.js App with a `--development` flag, and with the following entry script:

```js
const settings = {
  title: 'NW.js Angular2 Boilerplate',
  frame: true,
  width: 800,
  height: 600
};


if (nw.App.argv.includes('--development')) {
  // start your NW.js App with a --dev flag during development.
  // since you're serving your Angular App, tell NW.js to open your locally served Angular App

  nw.Window.open(
      'localhost:4200',
      settings,
      (win) => win?.showDevTools(),
  );
} else {
  // otherwise, after your build your Angular App, you tell NW.js to open the built index.html inside your build folder (usually called dist)
  
  nw.Window.open(
      'dist/index.html',
      settings,
      (win) => {},
  );
}
```

Point your package.json to your `entry.js` script:

```js
{
  name: 'NW.js Angular2 App',
  main: 'entry.js'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create app that runs locally in your browser when You run eg. index.html

Then You can like mentioned in [getting started](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/) set in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "main": "index.html"
}
```

And run app:

> Step 3. Run your app
>
> cd /path/to/your/app
>
> /path/to/nw .

Happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for responding... Angular 2 bootstraps using /src/app/app.componet.ts and this is the entry point that then calls /src/index.html

Comment: I suggest to first build your angular app (e.g. when using `angular-cli` it would be `ng build -prod --aot`. This creates a build directory where the entry point is its `index.html`. Didn't tried it but as I am curious, I will try it soon ;-)